# How to detect when the Player is not playing the game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, character, monodevelop

am making a game in unity but am at that point where i check if the game user is clicking anything or not.. So if the player is idle for certain amount of time, lets say 20 seconds then i will play an animation to indicate that the player is idle

Comment: Maybe set a `DateTime` field to `DateTime.UtcNow` when there is input. If `DateTime.UtcNow - lastInput` is greater than 20 seconds, play your animation.

Comment: Everyone who knows about the game is always playing the game.  Also, you just lost the game.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an entirely new script for this purpose ...

```
public static class IdleCheck
{
    public static int Timeout { get; set; }

    private static float lastAction;
    public static void ReportAction ()
    {
        lastAction = Time.time;
    }

    public static bool IsIdle
    {
        get { return (Time.time - time) > Timeout; }
    }
}
```

Every time the user reports an action, like clicking, simply call `IdleCheck.ReportAction()` and use `IdleCheck.IsIdle` wherever needed.

Comment: `Time.deltaTime`. Always use that for timing in Unity

Comment: @Programmer I believe you mean `Time.time` for this purpose. But thanks, I changed it.

Comment: I actually meant `Time.deltaTime` since it is more accurate than `Time.Time`. Just add it to your counter every frame.

Comment: @Programmer How would you do that, considering the class doesn't derive from `MonoBehaviour`?

Comment: What makes you thin that the class does not derive from MonoB?

Comment: @IanH. shouldnt both the class and the IsIdle property be static aswell? it makes no sense to have different instances of it anyway.

Comment: @yes Thanks, I missed that.

Comment: @Programmer What would be the benefits of making it a MonoBehaviour?

Comment: So that you can use the callback functions like `Start`, `Update` and also be able to attach it to a GameObject. If OP did not post post always assume that the script derives from MonoB because that's the default thing you will get when new script is created.

Comment: @Programmer See the first sentence of my answer, I assumed the best way to also give the possibility to call the `ReportAction` method was to create an entirely new class, which also is benificial for the modality of the project.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use events like e.mousePosition to see if it was moved and have a counter set up for 20 sec. If event e.mousePosition not triggered in 20 sec then play the idle animation. refer to Unity documentation here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Event-mousePosition.html

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should do it

anyClick should be true when you get a click.

```
float timeSinceLastClick = 0.0f;
void Update()
{
    timeSinceLastClick += Time.deltaTime;

    if(anyClick)
    {
        timeSinceLastClick = 0.0f;
        anyClick = false;
    }

    if(timeSinceLastClick > 20.0f)
    {
        //Play Idle animation
    }
}
```